# what is the time complexity of this for for for if

Tags: time-complexity

I need to know the analysis of time complexity of this case?

```
  for k=1:(N-1)
for i=1:N-1
    for j=1:N
        if (Groups22(i,j)==Groups2(k,I)& AA(i,j)==AA(k,I)& BB(i,j)==BB(k,I))
            Groups22(i,j)=nan;
        end
```

Comment: This should be simple enough for you to solve on your own if you learned about analyzing time complexity of functions. If you are still struggling, then **at least** explain what you have already tried and what specifically you don't understand.

Comment: I think it is n^3 but cannot be sure how "if" works here

Comment: Assuming all those functions `Groups2`, `AA`, `BB`, `Groups22` all work in constant time, then yes.

Comment: I guess those are not functions but array accesses, i.e., constant time.

Comment: @ReijoJaakkola, well, in some sense, they are function calls (at least from a programmer's point of view). These functions simply perform an array access. Either way, it's constant time.

Comment: (Are variable names case sensitive?)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's try to analyze this together, how? Take every line/instruction of the code and check its complexity.

**Simple example:**

```
Let tableA=[0,1,...9]
For i=0 to i=n
 tableA[i]=0;
```

Depending on the computation model (Random access machine, Turing machine with tape, etc), but we usually consider that tableA[i]=0 is an operation that accesses a position of the array in constant time. Why constant? Simply because it does not depend on the size of the table. So we say it's $O(1)$

Generally, all if, ==, =>, <=, assignement, array access, etc are all considered constant time operations.

Now let's take the loop, what does the loop (valid for and while loops) do? it repeats the instruction within the loop body n times. We can see that depending on the size of the tableA, the loop may take longer to complete. So we say it's $O(n)$ multiplied by the complexity of the operations within the loop, so $O(n) \times O(1) = O(n \times 1) = O(n)$

**Now in your case:**

We have some comparison operations, all of these happen in constant time since it's direct access to the array and simple equality test, the operation does not depend on the size of the array, so this operation is $O(1)$. This $O(1)$ operation is performed  in for loop, `for j=1:N` so it's performed n times. Just like the previous example I gave, We now multiply $O(1\times n) =O(n)$.

How many times to we repeat this inner for loop? we repeat it with for `i=1:N-1`so that's $O(n-1)$ in the complexity notation, the -1 (or a +1, or $\pm$ any constant) does not matter as they belong to the same complexity class. So we simply consider it $O(n)$. We repeat the following part that is $O(n)$: `for j=1:N if (....)...;` n times, so we have $O(n \times n) = O(n^2)$

Finally, repeat the same reasoning for the last outer loop  `for k=1:(N-1)` and we arrive $O(n^3)$

**Please note that these are NOT formal definitions of asymptotic complexity notation** there are good answers here on CS SE on how to formally define them (you should look at these) or you can look for some lecture notes on the topic.